# Does singleton class member function return same object every time?

Tags: kotlin, singleton

```
object Someclass {
   fun createEmployee(): Employee {
     return Employee("john", "1221")
  }
}
```

```
data class Employee(val name: String, number: String)
```

"When i call `Someclass.createEmployee()` does it return same employee object every time?"

"If it return new employee object every time. how to make`Someclass.createEmployee()` return same object every time?"

Comment: It returns a new one each time.

Answer (score 0):

It returns a new object each time. `Employee("john", "1221")` is calling the `Employee` constructor with the given arguments and returning a new object.

If you want to return the same object every time, you need to store the object in a variable somewhere and access that variable instead. Something like the following would make `createEmployee` return the same employee every time:

```
object Someclass {
    private var employee: Employee? = null

    fun createEmployee(): Employee {
        if ( employee == null )
            employee = Employee("john", "1221")
        return employee!!
    }
}
```

As you can see, the code checks if the employee exists and it creates a new one if necessary – but once an employee is created the same one is returned each time.

Comment: You could get the same effect much more concisely and with thread-safety using `by lazy`, e.g. `val employee: Employee by lazy { Employee("John", "1221") }`, and dispensing with the getter.  (In many cases, the overhead construction is low enough that I wouldn't even bother with that, and would just do `val employee = Employee("John", "1221")`.)

Comment: Sounds good. I thought I'd answer OP's question precisely and with a minimum of additional features since they seem very new to all this.